# Replace one character by the other (and vice-versa) in shell

Tags: shell, awk, sed, tr

Say I have strings that look like this:

```bash
$ a='/o\\'
$ echo $a
/o\
$ b='\//\\\\/'
$ echo $b
\//\\/
```

I'd like a shell script (ideally a one-liner) to replace `/` occurrences by `\` and vice-versa.

Suppose the command is called `invert`, it would yield (in a shell prompt):

```bash
$ invert $a
\o/
$ invert $b
/\\//\
```

For example using `sed`, it seems unavoidable to use a temporary character, which is not great, like so:

```bash
$ echo $a | sed 's#/#%#g' | sed 's#\\#/#g' | sed 's#%#\\#g'
\o/
$ echo $b | sed 's#/#%#g' | sed 's#\\#/#g' | sed 's#%#\\#g'
/\\//\
```

For some context, this is useful for proper printing of `git log --graph --all | tac` (I like to see newer commits at the bottom).

Comment: What shell are you using? In Bash, even the unquoted output doesn't replace any ``\\`` with ``\``.

Comment: Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and use https://www.shellcheck.net/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` is your friend:

```
% echo 'abc' | tr ab ba      
bac
% echo '/o\' | tr '\\/' '/\\'
\o/
```

(escaping the backslashes in the output might require a separate step)

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done with (g)awk:

```
$ echo a/\\b\\/c | gawk -F "/" 'BEGIN{ OFS="\\" } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/\\/,"/",$i); print $0; }'
a\/b/\c
$ echo a\\/b/\\c | gawk -F "/" 'BEGIN{ OFS="\\" } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/\\/,"/",$i); print $0; }'
a/\b\/c
$
```

- `-F "/"`  This defines the separator, The input will be split in "/", and should no longer contain a "/" character.
- `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/\\/,"/",$i);`.  This will replace, in all items in the input, the backslash (`\`) for a slash (`/`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace every instance of `/` with `\`, you can uses the [`y` command of sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-y-_0028transliterate_0029-command), which is quite similar to what `tr` does:

```
$ a='/o\'
$ echo "$a"
/o\
$ echo "$a" | sed 'y|/\\|\\/|'
\o/
$ b='\//\\/'
$ echo "$b"
\//\\/
$ echo "$b" | sed 'y|/\\|\\/|'
/\\//\
```

Comment: Great option in sed land. But still giving the `tr` answer the green tick as it is simplest.

Comment: Wow: I've been through the sed manpage backwards and forwards over the years, and used almost everything in there one way or another, and yet somehow the `y` command has never registered with me! I am illuminated.

Comment: (Incidentally, writing that replacement with `/` delimiters and without quotes, is an entertaining exercise in counting: `echo '/o\' | sed y/\\\\\\//\\/\\\\/`)

Answer (score 1):

If you are strictly limited to GNU `AWK` you might get desired result following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
\//\\\\/
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT=".";OFS="";arr["/"]="\\";arr["\\"]="/"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){if($i in arr){$i=arr[$i]}};print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
/\\////\
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field is any single character using `FPAT` built-in variable and that output field separator (`OFS`) is empty string and create array where key-value pair represent charactertobereplace-replacement, `\` needs to be escaped hence `\\` denote literal `\`. Then for each line I iterate overall all fields using `for` loop and if given field hold character present in array `arr` keys I do exchange it for corresponding value, after loop I `print` line.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*